# jqGrid's shrinkToFit causes horizontal scrollbar to appear

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid, scrollbar, shrink

I've started using jqGrid recently and encountered a problem which causes horizontal scrollbar when setting **shrinkToFit** option to **true**. Do you have any ideas how to get rid of it, as I don't need it in my table yet

Here's the JS piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "example.xml",
            datatype: "xml",
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames: ["Inv No", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Notes"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "invid" },
                { name: "invdate" },
                { name: "amount" },
                { name: "tax" },
                { name: "total" },
                { name: "note" }
            ],
            pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 2,
            rowList: [2, 4, 6],
            sortname: "invid",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            height: "auto",
            loadonce: true,
            styleUI: "Bootstrap",
            responsive: true,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            caption: "My first grid"
        });
        $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', 
           { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    });
})
```

[And here's the screenshot of unwanted scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYuuj.png)

Comment: Try [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) instead of commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you use currently. You can test it by changing URLs to jqGrid files to load it from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) and replace `styleUI: "Bootstrap"` option to `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap2.htm) an example of the usage.

Comment: @Oleg thank you, I'll give it a try